# Sleep identifier not found visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Just as mentioned in the documentation as well as online forums, I've used the Sleep function in the following way:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
Sleep(4)
```

Still I'm getting the build error:

```
'Sleep': identifier not found
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10

Comment: @MichaelWalz dude I clearly mentioned in the question I have included the header

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: Is the `#include <windows.h>` in the same file you are calling `Sleep(4)`? Or did you include that header elsewhere and forget to include it wher we're trying to `Sleep`?

Comment: Does this single file compile: `#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
  Sleep(1);
}`

Comment: @Thebluefish yeah I guess I need the place the header file in my custom project folder. Where would I find the required header?

Comment: No, you do not need to physically place the header file in your project. If it is finding the header (ie, you are not getting any compile errors stating `windows.h is not found`), then that is not your issue. However, it will need to be `#include`'d in any of your project files that need it. Is it `#include`'d at the top of your project file that calls `Sleep`? A common problem I see is `#include`'ing it elsewhere and forgetting about that requirement.

Comment: Try to create an all new C++ Windows console project and look if it compiles _there_

Comment: @Thebluefish Solved mate! Turns out you need to include the required headers in stdafx.h

Comment: Ah! You should look into precompiled headers (what `stdafx.h` is) - There are some gotchas that you should be aware of, if you decide to continue using them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

Include the required headers in stdafx.h which is in the project folder created